# Problema al extraer texto de un PDF

Tags: pdf

Necesito extraer texto de un PDF para lo cual uso pdftotext o pdftohtml según el caso. Sin embargo, me he encontrado con un PDF en el que mi script me falla. En el PDF el texto no está como imagen, pero al investigar un poco me he dado cuenta de que si copio en crudo texto del PDF con el ratón y lo pego en cualquier sitio, en vez de obtener los caracteres del texto, obtengo basura.

¿Alguien sabe por qué es esto? Yo creía que en los PDF los caracteres de texto eran eso, caracteres de texto. He probado a convertir el PDF a imagen y escanearlo con OCR luego y funciona, pero el resultado no es lo suficientemente satisfactorio, porque los errores del OCR hacen inviable que su resultado lo trate con el script.

El PDF que me da problemas es [este](http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/boja/2018/71/BOJA18-071-00107-6345-01_00133761.pdf). El texto de la orden se copia bien, pero el texto de todos los anexos se vuelve basura.

Comment: Yo he notado que dependiendo de la herramienta para crear pdf's que se utilice, los metacaracteres y la codificación varían sobre el mismo contenido.
Utilizando la biblioteca tika ( from tika import parser ) y luego haciendo ( pdf = parser.from_file('url al archivo') obtendrás un diccionario en el que puedes ver tanto el contenido del texto ( pdf['content'] ) como los metadatos ( pdf['metadata'] )
Añadir que he probado tu pdf con este método y hasta la página 93 lo extrae sin problema, a partir de ahí viene la fiesta.
Te dejo el enlace a tika. 
https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python

Comment: Prueba esta línea: 

unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", pdf['content']).encode("ascii","ignore").decode("ascii")

Mejora el texto recibido, quizá pueda ayudarte ( siguiendo lo que te comenté en el comentario anterior). Suerte!!